# Python Arguments in Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

Using the code from exercise 15 of Learn Python the Hard Way (by Zed Shaw), code of which is

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print "Here's your file %r:" % filename

print txt.read()

print "Type the filename again:"

file_again = raw_input("> ")

txt_again  = open(file_again)

print txt.again.read()
```

I'm trying to run this using Powershell. I've been able to run every other exercise this way.

When I run `python ex15.py ex15_sample.txt` in Powershell, it doesn't prompt for user input like the previous few exercises, but instead just gives me a blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me on OSX once I changed the last line to `print txt_again.read()`. If this doesn't work could you update your question with output from the console?

Comment: Let me try this now. I'm using Win 7 Home Premium

Comment: yeah, that was it. Thank you so much! I need to get better at recognizing typos... I'll mark the answer as correct when  it lets me.